# Angular and C# Large number with decimal automatically rounding

Tags: c#, angular, api

I have this issue, for example in my database I have this value of `100000000000000.165` and when I validate the result using API tester I get the expected value.

[image]

When I retrieve it in angular app, checking it via network tab in console log I get this value.

[image]

I'm not sure what is wrong, In my angular app entity I already used this code

```
public sctTotalPEO1?: BigNumber;
```

And in my C# api controller, here it is

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet("{yearid}")]
    public async Task<MyDto> GetData(int yearid)
            {
                MyDto ret = await _mySvc.GetDataAsync(yearid);
                return ret;
            }
```

And In my DTO, i have this property

```
public decimal? SctTotalPEO1 { get; set; }
```

Any idea how can I fix this issue? Thank you

Comment: Javascript literals are `doubles`, if you want more precision you'll need to use a library.

Comment: Floating point numbers are nasty, especially in the frontend. If you only need to display it and don't need to use it for calculations, I'd suggest simply sending it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show exact data whatever in database then use
public sctTotalPEO1?: string; instead of BigNumber because this will increase value after decimal point.